# Can we deploy BizTalk Accelerator for RosettaNet code as webapp(azure website)?

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I wonder do we really need a Biztalk VM only to deploy `BizTalk Accelerator for RosettaNet c# application code`.

Is there any way to deploy it as a webapp (azure websites) will code work with all dll with Local copy  = true ?  and give sql database connection string in web.config file?

I have this sample code from MSDN.

Default.cs

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request["Submit"] != null)
            {
                string sPipCode = Request["PipCode"];
                string sPipVersion = Request["PipVersion"];
                string sPipInstanceID = Request["PipInstanceID"];
                string sPipCategory = Request["PipCategory"];
                string sPipSource = Request["PipSource"];
                string sPipDestination = Request["PipDestination"];
                string sFileName1 = Request["FileName1"];
                string sFileName2 = Request["FileName2"];
                string sRemark1 = Request["Remark1"];
                string sRemark2 = Request["Remark2"];
                string[] aInputFiles = new string[2];
                string[] aRemarks = new string[2];
                string sContent = Request["ServiceContent"].Trim();

                SubmitRNIF MessageSubmitter = new SubmitRNIF();

                //The message category
                int mc;
                if (sPipCategory.ToUpper() == "RESPONSE")
                    mc = MessageCategory.AsyncResponse;
                else
                    mc = MessageCategory.AsyncAction;

                //Generate a Pip instance ID if the submitted value is null or empty
                if (sPipInstanceID.Length == 0)
                    sPipInstanceID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                //Generate the input attachment files arrary and its associated remarks
                if (sFileName1 != null && sFileName1.Length > 0) aInputFiles[0] = sFileName1;
                if (sFileName2 != null && sFileName2.Length > 0) aInputFiles[1] = sFileName1;
                if (sRemark1 != null && sRemark1.Length > 0) aRemarks[0] = sRemark1;
                if (sRemark2 != null && sRemark2.Length > 0) aRemarks[1] = sRemark2;

                if (sFileName1 == null && sFileName2 == null)
                    MessageSubmitter.SubmitMessage(mc, sPipSource, sPipDestination, sPipCode, sPipInstanceID, sPipVersion, sContent);
                else
                    MessageSubmitter.SubmitMessage(mc, sPipSource, sPipDestination, sPipCode, sPipInstanceID, sPipVersion, sContent, aInputFiles);

                Response.Redirect("QueryData.aspx?PIPInstanceID=" + sPipInstanceID);
                Response.End();
            }

        }
    }
```

QueryData.cs

```
public partial class QueryData : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Put user code to initialize the page here

            string IncomingQuery = @"SELECT PIPInstanceID as 'Instance ID', MessageCategory as 'Category', SourcePartyName as 'Source', DestinationPartyName as 'Destination', PIPCode as 'Code', PIPVersion as 'Version', TimeCreated as 'Time' FROM MessagesToLOB WHERE PIPInstanceID like '{0}' ORDER BY TimeCreated ASC";
            string OutgoingQuery = @"SELECT PIPInstanceID as 'Instance ID', MessageCategory as 'Category', SourcePartyName as 'Source', DestinationPartyName as 'Destination', PIPCode as 'Code', PIPVersion as 'Version', TimeCreated as 'Time' FROM MessagesFromLOB WHERE PIPInstanceID like '{0}' ORDER BY TimeCreated ASC";

            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            String sResponse = "";

            try
            {
                Request.ValidateInput();

                SqlConnection localConnection = new SqlConnection(RuntimeGlobal.DataDbConnectionString);
                string x = null;
                if (Request["PIPInstanceID"] != null && Request["PIPInstanceID"].Length > 0)
                    x = Request["PIPInstanceID"];
                else
                    x = "%";

                IncomingQuery = string.Format(IncomingQuery, x);

                SqlCommand localCommand = new SqlCommand(IncomingQuery, localConnection);

                localConnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader retReader = null;

                retReader = localCommand.ExecuteReader();
                DataGrid1.DataSource = retReader;
                DataGrid1.DataBind();
                Response.Flush();
                localCommand.Dispose();
                localConnection.Close();


                //Outgoing
                OutgoingQuery = string.Format(OutgoingQuery, x);

                localCommand = new SqlCommand(OutgoingQuery, localConnection);

                localConnection.Open();
                retReader = null;

                retReader = localCommand.ExecuteReader();
                DataGrid2.DataSource = retReader;
                DataGrid2.DataBind();
                Response.Flush();
                localCommand.Dispose();
                localConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                sResponse = "Could not access the database: " + ex.Message;
                Response.Write(sResponse);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well....while it's possible, maybe even probable, you could get it to work, it's definitely not supportable by Microsoft.

The stickler will be **licensing** since there is no provision for running any BizTalk SKU bits on anything other than licensed cores.  Meaning, even if you could get it to work, it's still not legit.

So, I'm going to say **NO**, a VM is your best and only option.

Comment: great thanks , you mean now I have to have use biztalk VM and i need to deploy that code into IIS of VM? How then I can access it from outside?

Comment: @Neo To be clear, you have to deploy all of BizTalk Sever + the RosettaNet Accelerator.  For access, just modify the Network Security properties to enable the Public Address and Port you want to use.

Comment: ok what about endpoint like any webapp / webapi having endpoint like .azurewebsites.net what about this biztalk applcaiiton endpoint ?